# automake putting object files after libraries

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, autotools, automake

`src/Makefile.am`:

```
myproj_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++17 -g -I/home/software/miniconda3/include -I$(top_srcdir)/external
myproj_LDFLAGS = -L/home/software/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/software/miniconda3/lib -fopenmp -lz -ligraph -pthread 
bin_PROGRAMS = myproj
myproj_SOURCES = gfa.cpp  graph.cpp myproj.cpp gfa.h  graph.h
bindir = $(top_srcdir)/bin
```

This builds the object files just fine, but when building the target, it tries running

```
g++ -fopenmp -O3 -std=c++17 -g -I/home/software/miniconda3/include -I../external -g -O2 -L/home/software/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/software/miniconda3/lib -fopenmp -lz -ligraph -pthread   -o myproj myproj-gfa.o myproj-graph.o myproj-komb.o
```

The issue with this is that the object files come after the library files, which causes the error

```
/home/software/miniconda3/lib/libz.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can easily fix this by adding the `-lz -ligraph` flags at the very end, but how can I get automake to add the `LDFLAGS` after the object files as opposed to before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're using the wrong variable. To pass libraries, you should use `myproj_LDADD`, not `myproj_LDFLAGS`.